# How could I remove the space of the top?

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the blank space of the top on the page.
Padding 0 doesn't work somehow.
This must work on IE8, 9.

Anybody please help me.

**html**

```
<body>
<div id="body">
    <div id="navigation">navigation</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-inner">content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</div>​
</body>
```

**test.css**

```
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    background-color: #FFCC66;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#content-inner {
    margin: 0 200px;
    background-color: #CC6633;
}

#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    background-color: #FF9966;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an image of the screen showing the different elements with a border around it? It'd hard to debug otherwise

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested your code on chrome and there's no white spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont have the div `body` with 0 padding?

***edit:***

if the `<div id="body">` is the only `<body>`'s child i would think its not needed? just use `<body>`

Answer (score 2):

```
body, div {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
```